# Transform data frame in R into 'Python dictionary'

Tags: r, list, dictionary, dataframe

I have data frame (df) with 2 columns e.g.

```
Project:      Person: 
1            a            
1            b              
2            a           
3            a
3            d
4            b
4            c
4            d
```

I want to get information about which projects each person took part. Something like Python dictionary.

```
'a': {1, 2, 3}, 'b': {1, 4}, 'c': {4}, 'd': {3, 4}
```

I know that R doesn't support dictionaries, but maybe something similar is possible using lists?

So then I can check, in which projects they took part together etc. (intersect)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `by`

```
lst <- by(df, df$Person, FUN = function(x) x$Project)
#df$Person: a
#[1] 1 2 3
#------------------------------------------------------------
#df$Person: b
#[1] 1 4
#------------------------------------------------------------
#df$Person: c
#[1] 4
#------------------------------------------------------------
#df$Person: d
#[1] 3 4
```

The return object of `by` is just a `list` so you can easily operate on its elements with `lapply`/`sapply`.

For example, to sum entries by `Person` you would do

```
sapply(lst, sum)
#a b c d
#6 5 4 7
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Project:      Person:
1            a
1            b
2            a
3            a
3            d
4            b
4            c
4            d", header = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split data.frame into list and transform it into JSON:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(split(d$Project, d$Person))
{"a":[1,2,3],"b":[1,4],"c":[4],"d":[3,4]}
```

If you want to use following data in R then use simple list:

```
split(d$Project, d$Person)
```

data:

```
structure(list(Project = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Person = c("a", 
"b", "a", "a", "d", "b", "c", "d")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```